# Compatibilidade Criptografia Android e Windows Phone

Tags: c#

Tenho uma aplicação em C# que gera informações no Windows Desktop e envia arquivos para aplicação em Android.

Envio as informações criptografadas com as funções abaixo, porém estou desenvolvendo a mesma aplicação do Android para Windows Phone e a função de Criptografar e Descriptografar não funcionam no Windows Phone pois `using System.Security.Cryptography` não é reconhecido.

Encontrei referências para o uso de `using Windows.Security.Cryptography` e `using Windows.Security.Cryptography.Core`, mas não tive sucesso.

Alguém já passou por esta situação e pode me dar uma sugestão para que estas funções ou equivalentes possam também ser utilizadas no Windows Phone?

```
public static string Criptografar(string chave, string Message)
{
    byte[] Results;
    System.Text.UTF8Encoding UTF8                = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
    MD5CryptoServiceProvider HashProvider        = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
    byte[] TDESKey                               = HashProvider.ComputeHash(UTF8.GetBytes(chave));
    TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider TDESAlgorithm = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
    TDESAlgorithm.Key                            = TDESKey;
    TDESAlgorithm.Mode                           = CipherMode.ECB;
    TDESAlgorithm.Padding                        = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
    byte[] DataToEncrypt                         = UTF8.GetBytes(Message);
    try
    {
        ICryptoTransform Encryptor = TDESAlgorithm.CreateEncryptor();
        Results                    = Encryptor.TransformFinalBlock(DataToEncrypt, 0, DataToEncrypt.Length);
    }
    finally
    {
        TDESAlgorithm.Clear();
        HashProvider.Clear();
    }
    return Convert.ToBase64String(Results);
}

public static string Descriptografar(string chave, string Message)
{
    byte[] Results;
    System.Text.UTF8Encoding UTF8                = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
    MD5CryptoServiceProvider HashProvider        = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
    byte[] TDESKey                               = HashProvider.ComputeHash(UTF8.GetBytes(chave));
    TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider TDESAlgorithm = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
    TDESAlgorithm.Key                            = TDESKey;
    TDESAlgorithm.Mode                           = CipherMode.ECB;
    TDESAlgorithm.Padding                        = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
    byte[] DataToDecrypt                         = Convert.FromBase64String(Message);
    try
    {
        ICryptoTransform Decryptor = TDESAlgorithm.CreateDecryptor();
        Results                    = Decryptor.TransformFinalBlock(DataToDecrypt, 0, DataToDecrypt.Length);
    }
    finally
    {
        TDESAlgorithm.Clear();
        HashProvider.Clear();
    }
    return UTF8.GetString(Results);
}
```